# Why won't the user input go inside the database despite success message?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, reactjs, debugging

I'm trying to store user input, which's supposed to be an email address, into the my database but it doesn't seem to be working despite getting the success message:

`INSERT INTO mydb.emails VALUES (''){"data":"You Data added successfully"}`.

(You can see this message in the `if` statement of my code in the php file).

I'm suspecting there's either something off with how I created my table and/or how I'm using the `$sql` variable inside the php file.

I've kind of ran into a wall and would like to know what I'm doing wrong?

Below I have all the information needed.

Here's my js file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ProductList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.addFormData = this.addFormData.bind(this);
    }

    addFormData(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('myEmail', this.refs.myEmail.value);
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            // 'Host' : 'sdb.amazonaws.com'
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        };
        axios.post("myEndPoint", headers, fd)
            .then(res => {
                alert(res.data.data);
            });
    }

    render() {
        let styles = this.state.modalVisible
            ? {display: "block"}
            : {display: "none"};
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                    <form>
                    <div className="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <input type="email" id="Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" ref="myEmail" />
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="submitEmail btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addFormData}>Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

here's my php file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$servername = "my host";
$username   = "my name";
$password   = "my pw";
$dbname     = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO innodb.emails
VALUES ('".$_POST['myEmail']."')";

echo $sql;

if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    $data = array("data" => "You Data added successfully");
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

Here's my SQL query to create the table that holds emails:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.emails(emails VARCHAR(200)); 
SELECT * FROM mydb.emails;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if PHP's `$_POST` works with JSON out of the box. I recall it working only with form-data or multipart. Perhaps you need to json decode the POST data yourself?

Comment: Additionally just concatenating data into your SQL string leaves a gaping SQL injection out there in the open. I highly recommend you look into [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Imagine if someone posts `'); DROP TABLE innodb.emails; --`. Now the query is `INSERT INTO innodb.emails VALUES (''); DROP TABLE innodb.emails; --')`. Blam.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating your table in one schema, but then trying to insert into an identical table in another schema:

```
INSERT INTO innodb.emails
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.emails
```

Note the `innodb` vs the `mydb`.  Do you have identical tables in two different schemas?  Maybe your just looking for your data in the wrong place?  Hope that helps.

For more information on schemas vs databases, check [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-key-difference-between-a-schema-and-a-database-with-respect-to-MySQL-Oracle-and-other-databases).